# tsqlt FakeTable not rolling back after unit test executed

Tags: sql, sql-server, unit-testing, tsqlt

I have an extremely simple unit test where I am testing the functionality of a tsqlt.FakeTable. However, after running the command and inserting data, it does not roll back to the previous state.

Current table:

[product01].[batch]

[image]

After executing the below code, the table is not rolled back to the above. It overrides the data and I can see the temp object created under tables.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [test_product].[test Given batch size of 1000 and batch qty of 2 When sp_insert_batch is called Then two entries populated in batch table]

AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @batch_count INT = 2
DECLARE @batch_size INT = 1000
DECLARE @job_number NVARCHAR(10) = '1000000000'


DECLARE @actual_batch_count INT
DECLARE @actual_batch_size INT

-- Arrange

EXEC tSQLt.FakeTable '[product01].[batch]'

INSERT INTO product01.batch(batch_id,batch_qty,date_from, date_to, job_number)
VALUES('6003',100,'2020-06-01', '2020-06-30','5000000000')


    
-- Act


-- Assert


END
```

Selecting the batch table after the above code has run:

[image]

I haven't written the actual assert logic, but I am confused as to why the table is not being rolled back. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tSQLt tests cannot be executed directly. You need to always use one of the run methods like `tSQLt.Run`

If you call the test directly as in `EXEC your.test;`, no rollback will happen and other tSQLt features won’t work either.

Comment: Wow, I feel like such a rookie. This solved my problem, thank you!